# Upload Image to Server using Swagger Api

Tags: .net, flutter, swagger

[image]

Please explain me about "fileToken". I am coding Flutter and I don't know how can I use this api.

Comment: take a look at the following answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71997666/15361613

Comment: With my limited knowledge I would say fileToken is a base64. But you who have access to the documentation want to know.

Comment: @Chance but max length of fileToken is 400. When I convert image to base 64, it is too long

Comment: Well then no then you should get in touch with whoever developed the api.